# npm broken after update to npm 5.4.0

Tags: node.js, npm

I updated npm from version 5.3.0 to 5.4.0 by running the following command in my workspace at cloud 9:

```
npm i -g npm
```

After the update I tried to install another package and this error was thrown:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:22:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
```

I tried reinstalling npm by running the command as suggested in the npm documentation:

```
curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

But that gave the following response:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/npm.6905/package/bin/read-package-json.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Generally there is a package manager involved in managing software, just running an install script to bypass it might cause problems. On which operating system is this happening?

Comment: I just followed the online documentation of the npm-package manager. Ubuntu 16.04. But as said I am working in a cloud, and it seemed not to have influenced my other environments.

Comment: Seems upgrading npm on Cloud9 can be tricky?
 https://community.c9.io/t/how-to-upgrade-npm/8441/4

Comment: I'm not sure why your question got downvoted (I actually voted it up because it helped me). However, even if you disagree with the critique, I'd like to suggest that you accept the answer provided. Unless it didn't help you and, in such case, please elaborate why and what's missing still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the 5.4.1 version is buggy. The only way I could get it to work was by turning back the version of npm down to 5.3.0

```
npm i -g npm@5.3.0
```

try this.

Comment: Do you have any link documenting this issue? We've got into problems too and it seems to be that many other should have whined about it leaving a digital trail of tears by now.